# Want to extract the links of the members given in 'view'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

want to extract the links in 'view' from 'next'page tab also,means from n number of pagess

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get('https://old.mciindia.org/InformationDesk/IndianMedicalRegister.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for links in soup.find('tr',class_='row'):
    for link in links.find('a',id_='lnkDesc'):
        print link['href']
```

Comment: is there a question? Also the url you are using doesn't match with what you are "asking". I don't see a 'view' or 'next page' or anything like that

Comment: url is same bro, you have to just put year of registration in the search box@chitown88

Comment: thanks bro. this should clearly be stated in the post/question.

Comment: sorry bro,I forgot to..@chitown88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should get you started:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time


url = 'https://old.mciindia.org/InformationDesk/IndianMedicalRegister.aspx'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Year of Registration')]").click()

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")[-1].send_keys("2015")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']").click()


soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'dnn_ctr588_IMRIndex_GV_Search'})
headers = [ header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th') ]

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'dnn_ctr588_IMRIndex_GV_Search'})
    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        if len(row.find_all('td')) == 7:
            data = row.find_all('td')

            name = data[4].text.strip()
            root_url = data[6].a['href'].split("'")[1]
            id_url = data[6].a['href'].split("'")[3]

            link = root_url + 'ViewDetails.aspx?ID=' + id_url

            print ('Name: %-50s\t Link: %s' %(name, link))

    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

Comment: you are awsm bro..@chitown88,can you me tell why you have used -1,what is the use of it?

Comment: So that particular input element, there are multiple (specifically 2 text field boxes). So I used -1 to basically say, use the last text field in the page/site. I could have alternatively used 1, which would mean take the 2nd text field. But if there were 3 elements, then the 2nd element wouldnt work for what we want, which is why I chose to take the last.

Comment: thanks bro understood.Can you tell me one more thing from where you have taken xpath for 'year of registration' and 'next' ?and what is the concept of [1]&[3] in root_url and id_url @chitown88

Comment: That link was stored as a string for JavaScript. So had to split the string up and pull out the substrings to ultimately put back together into the valid link. The 1 and 3 were just taking those substrings that were split (so take the 2nd part, and 4th part). If you get a chance, read up on lists and how those work. Those numbers are just referring to the specific values I wanted from a list.